# Oracle Database Project for Visual Studio 2017 - wrong table creation order when foreign keys are present

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, odp.net, database-project, odac

With Visual Studio 2017, started an Oracle Database Project (version 2) from scratch, and added two new tables, "Parent" and Child":

[Database project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47dbd.png)

Parent.sql contains:

```
CREATE TABLE BDT.Parent 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Child.sql contains:

```
CREATE TABLE BDT.Child 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    ParentID INT NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_CHILD_PARENT" FOREIGN KEY (ParentID)
    REFERENCES "BDT".Parent ("ID")
);
```

"BDT.Child" has a foreign key reference to "BDT.Parent", so "BDT.Parent" should be created first. But when I build the project (right-clicking over the project node and selecting "build"), the script generated in the bin folder is as follows:

```
--
-- CHILD
--
CREATE TABLE BDT.Child 
(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  ParentID INT NOT NULL,
  Description VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_CHILD_PARENT" FOREIGN KEY (ParentID)
  REFERENCES "BDT".Parent ("ID")
);
--
-- PARENT
--
CREATE TABLE BDT.Parent 
(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  Description VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL
);
--
-- FK_CHILD_PARENT
--
ALTER TABLE "BDT"."CHILD" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_CHILD_PARENT" FOREIGN KEY ("PARENTID") REFERENCES "BDT"."PARENT"("ID") ENABLE;
```

I see two main issues here:

- The ordering of the "CREATE TABLE" statements seems to be alphabetic-based. If I change the Child table name to "ZChild" then it is placed at the end of the script.
- The foreign key constraint seems to be duplicated. It is included in the CREATE statement and at the end of the script as an ALTER statement.

I can't find any reference to this particular problem, nor any complains. Is anything wrong with this particular set up?

I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.7)
- Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio shipped with ODAC for Visual Studio 2017 (12.2.0.1.1)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've confirmed that this is a rather severe bug unfortunately. This should be fixed in the next release, however releases are somewhat infrequent.

Comment: @ChristianShay Is this the official place to report this issue or should I post it anywhere else? Do you have any guess-timate about the next release date?